# In VPS with OS Ubuntu 18.04 "apt install nginx" shows libc6 & libcrypt1 error. So, how to install libc6 & libcrypt1 in it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to host node app on vps using nginx server. But I am unable to install nginx in ubuntu 18.04 version after apt install nginx shows:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.28) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6 is to be installed
         Depends: libcrypt1 (>= 1:4.1.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Anyone face such problem & how do you solve it? I also got problem in nginx.cnf, after nginx -t to check it shows brotil error.
[ubuntu nginx installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFoQA.png)

node app

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

I want to host node app to serve backend API's. So, I bought VPS from Hostinger website & have installed Ubuntu v18.04 in it. Then I successfully installed nodejs to run nodeapp & pm2 to manage processes. It was successfully running on port 8000. But problem is when I called the API from frontend, shows SSL security error.
So, for that I tried to install nginx but shows error & I guess for SSL nginx server is required. Now I am stuck in nginx installation.
I need some solution from someone who also face same problem.

Comment: Can you install docker? it's well suited for such issues, then you can use it as a proxy for your nodejs app

Comment: @Deano Docker is not a solution for everything... Just reinstall the packages and configure the package manager correct.

Comment: I am new to hosting & server related things. I have followed steps for hosting by looking tutorials in youtube & they didn't face such issue. Docker will be complicated for me to understand. I want only SSL for my app's IP address which is running on port 3000. So, is there any way get SSL without nginx or any alternative of nginx ?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider upgrading to more recent versions of ubuntu as version 18.04 will reach EOL on April 30, 2023

Otherwise, you may try upgrading packages on your system, as it currently has `libc6` version `2.27` while version `2.28` or higher is required.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

if you continue seeing an issue, you may try

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had installed Ubuntu v18.04 with plex control panel. I guess that is giving me the issue.
Now I installed Ubuntu v18.04 only. It is working fine now. I successfully installed nginx and it is running properly.